# How to prove logarithmic complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2) { ... }
```

Things like that are the signatures of logarithmic complexity.

But how get log(N)?

Could you give mathematical evidence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Useful reference on algorithmic complexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

On the nth iteration,

```
i = 2^n
```

We know that it iterates until `i >= N`

Therefore,

```
i < N
```

Now,

```
2^n = i < N

N > 2^n

log2 N > log2 (2^n)

log2 N > n
```

We know it iterates n times, being less than log2 N.

Thus `# iterations < log2 N`, or `# iterations` is `O(log N)`

QED. Logarithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying `N` by 2 adds one more iteration, regardless of the size of `N`. That's pretty much the definition of the log function -- it goes up by a constant amount every time you multiply `N` by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work untill `i < N`, and each step `i *= 2`. We say your loop has logarithmic complexity if it runs `log(N) + const` times. `2 ^ log(N) = N`, so after `[log(N)] + 1` times `i > N`.